# GPUImage camera not opening

Tags: ios, xcode, gpuimage

I am using Xcode 6.1 with iOS SDK 8.1.

I added the static library as described on Github readme and added this code.

```
GPUImageStillCamera *rearCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] init];
    rearCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *filter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
    [rearCamera addTarget:filter];
    [filter addTarget:_viewRoot];

_viewRearCamera.hidden=YES;
_viewFrontCamera.hidden=YES;
_viewAdMobBG.hidden=YES;

[rearCamera startCameraCapture];
```

`_viewRoot` is a GPUImageView instance in Storyboard which is connected to VC as `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPUImageView *viewRoot;`

All I get is white screen and the camera won't load. I am using latest GPUImage code from Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after wasting 2.5 days I concluded that the camera instance variable and filter instance variable needs to be global.

Thus I can't use `GPUImageStillCamera *rearCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] init];` but define `rearCamera` as global variable in header file similarly with `GPUImageBrightnessFilter *filter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];`